# Display Google Maps as Part of Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

How can we display google maps as part of android app ? I want to display google maps sharing screenspace with other elements like textbox and labels etc.Dont want maps to take up whole screen space.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Fragment inside of your Activity and inflate Google Maps into the Fragment programmatically.

Follow the link here to learn about working with Fragments: 
[Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)